# POST запрос при помощи HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, сервер, http, post

Как послать POST запрос на сервер при помощи класса `HttpURLConnection`?
С GET запросами все более менее понятно. Хотелось бы увидеть пример кода отправки GET запроса на сервер при помощи `HttpURLConnection`.

Допустим у меня есть переменная `editTextLogin = "Vasya"` и  `editTextPassword = "123"`

Каким образом я могу послать их на сервер?

Comment: если вашей целью является именно запрос в сеть с android устройства, то посмотрите на библиотеку retrofit 2. Даже в своей документации android предлагает её как инструмент для запросов в сеть. Если же ищете примеры с HttpUrlConnection, то можете просто поискать примеры на java без привязки к android

Comment: Почему httpUrlConnection не подходит для андроид?

Comment: подходит, просто с помощью данной библиотеки работать с запросами проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример создания **post** запроса:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){}
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { 
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://studytutorial.in/post.php");
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("name", "abc");
            postDataParams.put("email", "abc@gmail.com");
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
         }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}
    }
}
```

Пример взять с [этого ресурса](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial), перейдя по ссылке вы можете найти больше примеров.

Retrofit это библиотека, которая позволяет удобно работать с запросами. Идея простым языком: Retrofit строит URL с помощью описанного метода в интерфейсе и делает запрос используя OkHttp. Немного истории о OkHTTP и HttpURLConnection - можно прочитать [здесь.](https://habr.com/post/281965/) (статья является доп. материалом, а не частью основного ответа на вопрос).