# Как передать несколько переменных с приложения Android, написанном на языке java на сторонний сервер

Tags: java, веб-сервер

В общем, в приложении имеется несколько переменных - longitude, laritude, distance и velocity. Данные переменные необходимо передать из этого приложения(java) на сервер sweb для дальнейшей обработки. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/920107/post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-httpurlconnection или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579709/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4556/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-https-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу таким образом

```
package ru.geokrasnodar.gk_tracker;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class easyLevel {
    public static void sendPost() throws Exception {
        final OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        // параметры формы
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("latitude", "45")
                .add("longitude", "38")
                .add("velocity", "10")
                .add("distance", "500")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://geokrasnodar.ru/post.php")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "OkHttp Bot")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        try (Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            // Вывести ответ в консоль
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
    }
}
```